# how do you Notify the ViewModel if you change values of a collection in the View

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have ListView in my xaml(View) whose itemsSource is bound to an Observable collection.

MyView:

```
        <ListView x:Name="TestVariables" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding TestVariables}"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="White" Width="350">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="175"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="175"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Text="{Binding Key}"/>

                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Text="{Binding Value}"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Question:  So when i run my app and change my TextBox values, how do i get a new collection in my view model which has those changes only? I want to use that new collection somewhere in my code. In other words how do i notify my viewmodel of these changes?

For example if i run this, i would get: age 23,
                                        sex female,
                                        height 2

if i change my textboxes to :           age 24,
                                        sex male,
                                        height 2

I want to build a new collection in my viewModel of: age 24,
                                                     sex male

Here is my ViewModel:

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
   public ObservableCollection TestVariables { get; set; }

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        TestVariables= new ObservableCollection<TestVariable>
        {
            new TestVariable() {Key = "age", Value = 23},
            new TestVariable() {Key = "sex", Value = "female"},
            new TestVariable() {Key = "height", Value = 2}
        };
    }
}
```

TestVarible Class  :

```
public class TestVariable
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set;}

}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Try to set `Binding` mode to `TwoWay`. Somethig like `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestVariables, Mode=TwoWay}"`.

Comment: Attach your own event handler to PropertyChanged on each collection object. Use the collection changed event on the Viewmodel to attach your handler. Of course testvariable will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should notify changes for TestVariables property too. And then set binding mode as TwoWay binding on the UI.

```
private ObservableCollection<TestVariable> testVariables;
public ObservableCollection<TestVariable> TestVariables 
{ 
   get{return testVariables;}
   set
   {
     if(testVariables != value)
       {
         testVariables = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("TestVariables");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Tee, please read [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) his answer if it's helped.  Thanks.

Comment: The above solution worked but i noticed later that i also want a collection of values that have changed only. Raising Property changed for the whole collection gives me back the a collection that includes the values which i didn't change. I only want a collection of values which have changed. Using the above example, if i change age to 26, i should get that only, not: age 26, sex female, height 2